# Best PHP.ini settings to improve security

Tags: security, php

What core **php.ini** file settings we need to pay much attention in terms of improving security?

Comment: It's simple and to the point. 'What core php.ini file settings we need to pay much attention in terms of improving security?'  Cant get any better than that - simple English guys :P

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can begin with:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/php-security-best-practices-tutorial.html

it has a lot of practices to start dealing with security.
This link provides several issues to start with such as:

1. XSS
2. SQL injection
3. File uploads
4. Including local and remote files
5. eval()
6. Cross-site request forgery - CSRF